# How to download a '.noindex' file properly

Tags: javascript, php, html, download

I'd like to make an android '.noindex' file, basically an empty text file with no filename and the extension noindex --> '.noindex' (here some [info](http://android2know.blogspot.de/2013/01/create-nomedia-file.html)), downloadable when you click a link on simple html page.

First approach I used: a simple href

```
<a href="../static/download/.nomedia">.nomedia</a>
```

Results:

- 'save as' context menu needed to download = big disadvantage
- ***Firefox:*** downloaded file is saved as a '**nomedia**' file (filename only) but not a '**.nomedia**' file (no filename + nomedia extension)
- ***Chrome:*** manual renaming of filename from '**nomedia.txt**' to '**.nomedia**' in save as dialog needed
- ***Internet Explorer 11***: manual renaming of filename from '**.nomedia.nomedia**' to '**.nomedia**' in save as dialog needed

As this does not work at all, I thought I'd use a simple PHP script:

```
<?php

$file = "../download/.nomedia";
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=.nomedia");
readfile($file);
```

and the following href:

```
<a href="../static/php/download_nomedia.php">.nomedia</a>
```

Results:

- save as dialog appears directly = big advantage
- ***Firefox:*** again, the downloaded file is saved as a '**nomedia**' file (filename only) but not a '**.nomedia**' file (no filename + nomedia extension)
- ***Chrome:*** the same here, the downloaded file is saved as a '**nomedia**' file (filename only) but not a '**.nomedia**' file (no filename + nomedia extension)
- ***Internet Explorer 11***: downloaded file is saved as a '**.nomedia[1]**' file

The problem of an indirect download is solved, but the file that's downloaded using these 3 prominent browsers is never a '.noindex' file.

Does anyone know a fix for the php script above, or some other approach I could use to make a '.noindex' file downloadable?

Maybe it's even impossible to download this kind of file in html directly. I could zip the file and use this zip file with the php script from above. But I'd like to avoid zipping it, and thats why I'm asking you guys.

Maybe someone knows a 'dirty hack' to solve this issue?

Cheers

Comment: Windows explorer doesn't let you create a "dot" file. You have to do it from a command prompt.

Comment: The explorer does not, but with notepad you can create one: Please open the windows notepad, click file + 'save as', remove the '*.txt' file name, set the filetype to 'All files *.*', set the filename to  '.noindex', click save. Voila, you have a '.noindex' file

Comment: did I say notepad? No, I said Windows Explorer

Comment: Sorry read over it, and thought of the notepad...

Comment: But it's not about creating the file, it's about downloading it from a webserver. Using the first approach and Chrome or the Internet Explorer (after the renaming in the browsers 'save as' dialog) a '.nomedia' was created properly.